# categorize uploaded files

Tags: asp.net

I have a webapplication for uploading and showing files(Image and video).The administrator can upload files and the users can view this files.Now i am inserting the details of file to the sqlserver and populating links for the corresponding file in the user's form.There may have images and videos.

> I want to categorize the image and
>   video files;ie ,i want to show files
>   in two separate folders(Images and
>   Videos)

.This Categorizing also in sql(there should have a category table and it should be related with fileM table.

If anyone can help me please..
thank you

Comment: Improve your accptance rate to mark some question that help you as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect the mime type of the file. Have a look at this question in stackoverflow..
[How should I detect the MIME type of an uploaded file in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81283/asp-net-how-to-detect-file-upload-mime-type)