# Image upload validation in .NET

Tags: .net, security, image, validation

I've got a page where the user can upload an image which is later saved on the server. I'm doing simple validation of the uploaded file by checking its extension (.jpg, .png, etc.)

Is such validation enough for server security? Or does this leave the opportunity for someone to upload malicious code which can harm my server? If it is possible to validate the uploaded images, how it can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever end users put *anything* on your server, there is a chance for malicious behavior. While it's unlikely that double clicking on a .jpg image will hork your box, stranger things have been known to happen. (For example, who knew PDFs could contain so many security problems!)

Your best bet is to try actually loading the image and seeing if it the GDI+ libraries recognize it as a valid image. If you don't get a runtime exception, then you know that the image is 'valid'. This however won't protect you in the case that loading the image in GDI+ doesn't hork your box in the first place.

You can further protect yourself by loading the image in a separate AppDomain, but at narrows down the potential threats.

Answer (score 1):

You can generally read/check the MIME type of the file, by using the `urlmon.dll`. See this excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81283/asp-net-how-to-detect-file-upload-mime-type/1238450#1238450).

It's also not a bad idea to have a good anti virus program installed on your server. Enable the real time file system scanning and when the file is gone a moment after it was uploaded it contained most likely malicious code.

Answer (score 1):

With that validation, anyone can upload anything as long as they give it the extension you're looking for. Vulnerabilities depend on what you're doing with them. If you are re-serving them, the people receiving them could be compromised. It would take some creativity to do something malign with them, but my gut says it could be done.

This answer ([Validate image from file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210650/validate-image-from-file-in-c)) appears to have some thoughts on actually validating the images programmatically.