# upload only document files

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

i am trying to upload documents .user can be able to upload theri documents but he/she can be upload images istead of documents and i want to d restrict about this how to apply condition this is my upload code

```
            if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile != null && 
             FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength 
            > 0)
        {
            if
                (FileUploadControl.FileContent.Length < 100000)
            {
                string filename = 
                Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName);
                string folder = Server.MapPath("~/Docfiles/");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
                FileUploadControl.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(folder, filename));
                try
                {
                    cc.upload1(Txt_docde.Value, txt_dname.Value, 
              FileUploadControl.FileName, Convert.ToInt32(Docdrop.SelectedValue),
                       Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue), 
              Convert.ToString(Session["Login2"]),Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]));
                    StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    //StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold;
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Success";
                }
                catch
                {
                    StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    Label2.Text = "Failed";


                }
            }
                else
            {
                 StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            Label2.Text = "File Size to big";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make generic list of extensions you want to allow and then check if file you are trying to upload meets that extension requirement.

```
var allowedExtensions = new string[] { "doc", "docx", "pdf" };
var extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower().Replace(".", "");

if (allowedExtensions.Contains(extension))
{
    // Good to go
}
```

Here is full code for you

```
if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile != null && FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
{
    var allowedExtensions = new string[] { "doc", "docx", "pdf" };
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower().Replace(".", "");

    if (FileUploadControl.FileContent.Length < 100000 && allowedExtensions.Contains(extension))
    {
        string filename = 
        Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName);
        string folder = Server.MapPath("~/Docfiles/");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
        FileUploadControl.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(folder, filename));

        try
        {
            cc.upload1(Txt_docde.Value, txt_dname.Value, FileUploadControl.FileName, Convert.ToInt32(Docdrop.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue),  Convert.ToString(Session["Login2"]),Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]));
            StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            StatusLabel.Text = "Success";
        }
        catch
        {
            StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            Label2.Text = "Failed";
        }
    }
    else
    {
         StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
         Label2.Text = "File Size to big";
    }
}
```

Comment: i add this above this code or somwhere else...if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile != null && FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {

Comment: You can add this just after you check for size `FileUploadControl.FileContent.Length < 100000`. You can pretty much add this code anywhere you want before `CreateDirectory` or `SaveAs` functions since no point in checking file when you already saved it, right? :)

Comment: ok now in this ..if (allowedExtensions.Contains(extension))
{
    // Good to go
} what code i write?

Comment: in this you want to actually save the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to validate the file type suffix that you are interested in:

```
if (string.Equals(fileExt, ".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {...}
```

Comment: somebody can easily updload document.exe.pdf (where some users dont have show file extensions and any hacker can change the icon to make it look like a word or pdf file) and send a fake MIME type(per other answer and you have a malicious document on your server.  so I would just change above that to make sure there is no list of all todays executable files .exe msi zip rar shs

Answer (score 1):

You need to either check the extension of the posted file or its MIME type to detect whether it's the right format.

Go get the MIME type, check the `ContentType` property.

[ASP.NET How to get MIME Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81283/asp-net-how-to-detect-file-upload-mime-type)

Comment: security wise, the mime type technically can be faked.  But this is the correct answer, and it would also be wise to check the file extension as well as given below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look for a specific file type you can use the Path.GetExtension method.

```
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);

    if (fileExtension == ".doc") //or whatever file type your looking for
      {
        try
         { do your work }
      }
```